# Populating <intput type=datetime-local> and display it's value in the input field

Tags: angular, html, input

I have a reactive form in my angular project, and I try to populate it on the `edit` action from the database. Actually, the value is set properly, but the value isn't displayed in the input field with the `type=datetime-local`. The code for the reactive form is:

```
this.client = new FormGroup({
  'desired_installation_date': new FormControl(this.clientData['desired_installation_date'], Validators.required),
  //other controls
});
```

And the html form:

```
<form [formGroup]="client" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" *ngIf="client">
  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" formControlName="desired_installation_date">
  <!--Other inputs and submit button-->
</form>
```

Here is how it looks like in a view, however, the value is set:

[image]

The output of `console.log(this.clientData['desired_installation_date']);` is `2017-08-10T15:00:00.000Z`

What is the way to display the input's value in the input itself? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple, I just had to `split` the value like: `this.clientData['desired_installation_date'].split('.')[0]`. After that, the input field is filled with it value.